# django - resize images with pil

Tags: python, django

In my app In the save method I am compressing uploaded images. Now I want to also resize the images if they are very large. I played around with PIL in a test environment and came up with this code that works as expected.

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open('img.jpg')

(w,h) = image.size
if (w > 2000):
    i = image.size   # current size (height,width)
    i = i[0]//2, i[1]//2  # new size
    image = image.resize(i, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    image.save('halfresizesssd.jpg')
```

However when I try to merge it into my django project I get this error

`'int' object is not subscriptable - i = i[0]//2, i[1]//2  # new size`

If i understand the error correctly it is because i am passing an int as an array, I dont really understand that because if i try and pass say `2` instead of `i` i get the same error. I tried to just resize the image and skip the compression but I was still getting the same error

```
def compress(image):
    im = Image.open(image)
    # create a BytesIO object
    im_io = BytesIO() 
    #resize image
    im = im.convert("RGB")
    im = im.save(im_io,'JPEG', quality=70, optimize=True) 
    # create a django-friendly Files object
    new_image = File(im_io, name=image.name)

    w = new_image.size
    if (w > 1000):
        i = new_image.size   # current size (height,width)
        i = i[0]//2, i[1]//2  # new size
        new_image = new_image.resize(i, Image.ANTIALIAS)

    return new_image
```

Starting code

```
def compress(image):
                im = Image.open(image)
                # create a BytesIO object
                im_io = BytesIO() 
                #resize image
                im = im.convert("RGB")
                im = im.save(im_io,'JPEG', quality=70, optimize=True) 
                # create a django-friendly Files object
                new_image = File(im_io, name=image.name)
                return new_image

class Post(models.Model):
    ....
    image = models.ImageField(storage=PublicMediaStorage(), upload_to=path_and_rename, validators=[validate_image])

def save(self, *args, **kwargs): 
    self.slug = slugify(self.title)

    if self.image:
        # call the compress function
        new_image = compress(self.image)
        # set self.image to new_image
        self.image = new_image

    super(Post,self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: in first code you get `size` from `PIL.Image` but in next code you get `size` from `File` which uses `size` as number of bytes in file (single value), not `[width,height]` of image (list of two values). `File` doesn't know what you have in file - image, sound, PDF, Excel - and it doesn't know `[width,height]`. You have to use `im` instead of `new_image`, You have to first resize `im` and later convert it to `File()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test it but you use two different object.

In first code you work all time with `PIL.Image()` and its `size` gives `(width,height)` but in second code you works with `File()` and its `size` gives number of bytes in file (single number), not `(width,height)` (two numbers.

You have to first resize `PIL.Image` and later convert it to `File()`

Something like this (but I can't test it)

```
def compress(image):
    
    # --- resize ---
    
    img = Image.open(image)
    img = img.convert("RGB")

    (w, h) = img.size   # current size (width, height)

    if w > 1000:
        new_size = (w//2, h//2)  # new size
        img = img.resize(new_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    
    # --- convert to File ---

    im_io = BytesIO() 
    img.save(im_io, 'JPEG', quality=70, optimize=True) 

    new_image = File(im_io, name=image.name)

    return new_image
```

Comment: Thank you! going to try it out now, Update it works!

Comment: BTW: you could resize in scale - `scale = w / 1000` and `new_size = (int(w//scale), int(h//scale))` and you should get all images with width `1000`

Comment: I honestly don't have a specific width I was just having issues with users uploading very large images such as 6000x4000 and needed a way to cut them down. Would you go about it a different way?

Comment: all solutions have to use `Pillow` - but I found module [django-django-resized](https://github.com/un1t/django-resized) which adds `ResizedImageField` which can use `size=[1000,1000]`. In source code I see it also uses `Pillow`. It can has also other useful functions - i.e. rotate images (in settings `NORMALIZE_ROTATION`) because some phones, cameras may create rotated images (with extra tag about rotation) and not all tools can display it in correct orientation.